# Auto increment the minor version for Ant build/version.properties and setting it in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: ant, maven-versions-plugin, gitlab-ci.yml

We are using the ant build tool in our project. We have build.xml and stored the properties in build/version.properties. I am facing issues in task setting up a minor version from build.properties to GitLab-ci.yml. I want this minor version to increment after every commit. I am attaching some images for reference of build.xml[script for updating the minor version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BCRG.jpg).
In gitlab-ci.yml we define a
variable: MANEN_CLI_OPTS:" -s settings.xml --batch-mode -Dcc5_majorversion=5.143 -Dcc5_minor_version=$CI_PIPELINE_IID"